# Cannot `cd` into directory made by docker in a mounted volume

Tags: linux, docker

I'm running the following docker command:

```
docker run -v /data/polygon/mainnet:/data ghcr.io/streamingfast/firehose-ethereum:v1.2.2-polygon-v0.3.2-fh2.1 start reader-node --common-chain-id=137 --common-network-id=137 --data-dir=/data <other args>"
```

Note that I'm mounting `/data/polygon/mainnet` to `/data` and that `/data` is being used as the `data-dir` arg.

When this container starts up, it creates files and folders in `/data` in the container which I can see from the host:

```
12:11PM /data/polygon/mainnet
 ❯❯❯ ls
reader  storage
```

However, when I try to `cd` into one of the directories I get denied:

```
12:15PM /data/polygon/mainnet/reader  ✘ 1
 ❯❯❯ cd /data/polygon/mainnet/reader/data
cd: permission denied: /data/polygon/mainnet/reader/data
12:15PM /data/polygon/mainnet/reader  ✘ 1
 ❯❯❯ sudo !!
12:15PM /data/polygon/mainnet/reader  ✘ 1
 ❯❯❯ sudo cd /data/polygon/mainnet/reader/data
sudo: cd: command not found
```

But, I can `cd` into the `reader directory no problem:

```
12:16PM /home/ubuntu
 ❮❮❮ cd /data/polygon/mainnet/reader
12:16PM /data/polygon/mainnet/reader
 ❯❯❯ ls
data  work
```

If I list the folders under `reader` I see the following

```
12:17PM /data/polygon/mainnet/reader
 ❯❯❯ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root 42 Jan 11 12:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root 47 Jan 11 12:11 ..
drwx------ 4 root 33 Jan 11 12:11 data
drwxr-xr-x 3 root 41 Jan 11 12:11 work
```

Which is odd because the `reader` directory is owned by `root`, just like the `data` directory.

Why can't I `cd` into the `data` directory?

Ninja edit: turns out running `chown -R ubuntu data` solves the issue. I do still wonder why I couldn't `cd` into `data` but I could `cd` into `reader`.

Comment: So do you know what `drwx------` means? vs `drwxr-xr-x`?

Comment: No I don't but let me go learn!

Comment: Ah, looks like the directory cannot be read by the group or by others which is why I couldn't cd into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @KamilCuk for getting me to look into the specific permissions on the `data` directory.

Looks like only the owner of the `data` dir has permissions to read it.